# Boxplot axes and categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, categorical-data

I am new to R, and I am trying to figure out a problem for a class I am taking. I have one numerical variable (`Bwt`) and a categorical variable (`Sex`). I can make a simple boxplot with `Sex` on the x axis and `Bwt` on the y axis:

```
boxplot(Bwt ~ Sex)
```

What I need is to have `Sex` on the y axis and `Bwt` on the x axis, but it keeps saying it cannot because `Sex` is non-numerical (2 factors: `M` and `F`, in the dataset).

I also tried using `ggplot2`, and `geom_boxplot + coord_flip` and it gives me `NULL` with no boxplot at all. I know this is probably really simple to do, but I just can't figure it out! Is there a way for R to read my categorical variable as numeric or just an easier way? Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: A quick look at `?boxplot` reveals that there is a `horizontal` parameter, that one can set to `TRUE`. Your ggplot2 strategy _should_ work, but I can't tell what would be wrong with it since you aren't showing us any code or a reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure where is the problem as you do not provide sample data. But hope this help:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Bwt = rnorm(100),
                 Sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = T))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(Sex), y = Bwt)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And there is solution with base `boxplot`:

```
boxplot(Bwt ~ Sex, data = df, horizontal = T)
```

[image]